# exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH% when trying go build

Tags: windows, go, build, hyperledger-fabric, cgo

I am using Windows 10. When I tried to build [Chaincode](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode.html) it reported this error

```
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11 
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

My chaincode imports:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
)
```

It's running fine in [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: go build  command giving the above gcc error ... how can i solve it

Comment: Do you have `gcc` installed?

Comment: no .. is it required ?

Comment: Well, yes of course.

Comment: @jaswanth: Your error message is `"gcc": executable file not found`. That should be your first clue that "gcc" is required but not found.

Comment: fabric uses cgo, and cgo needs gcc.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

[gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (the GNU Compiler Collection) provides a C compiler. On Windows, install [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download). The [`github.com/miekg/pkcs11`](https://github.com/miekg/pkcs11) package uses [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/). Cgo enables the creation of Go packages that call C code.

Comment: tq it worked but getting different error now `.\hyperledger\fabric\vendor\github.com\miekg\pkcs11\pkcs11.go:29:18: fatal error: ltdl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Comment: I installed [libtools](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libtool.htm) but its not working

Comment: jaswanth, check out the answer @Ashinkel has given. I did have the same problem, but that worked for me.

Comment: When downloading the TDM-GCC installer for Windows, use the x64 version.  The 32-bit version did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: Installation of TDM-GCC [https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/] works fine for me Windows 10 testing execution with fyne [https://fyne.io]

Comment: If you are using VSCode, after installing TDM-GCC you will need to close VSCode and reopen it. This is needed so that the VScode terminal is updated and the gcc command can be found.

Answer (score 150):

If you are running Ubuntu do:

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

This solved the problem. It installs the gcc/g++ compilers and libraries.

Comment: use this command, when you are facing the issue in Ubuntu with sudo

Comment: If you are facing with dependencies when installing try ‘sudo aptitude install build-essential’

Comment: Which Ubuntu shell stores the path in a variable called %PATH%?

Comment: Worth noting that build-essential is not required to build Go source code, so you might not need this until you install a dependency that needs it to build

Comment: The OP is using Windows!

Answer (score 27):

I also encountered this message, but in my case, it was missing `gcc.exe`. I used [choco](https://chocolatey.org/) and installed `mingw`, and then it worked.

details:

1. download [choco](https://chocolatey.org/install)
2. `choco install mingw -y`
3. check: `gcc -v`

Comment: Also works with scoop: `scoop install mingw`

Comment: Quick question, why does this not work if you just install gcc directly with scoop (e.g. scoop install gcc)?

Answer (score 19):

1) Install `.exe` from > https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

1.2) ! use `x86_64` architecture

2) Add `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin` to `PATH` in `User Variables` and in `System Variables`. For me it works.

! To edit `Path` variable press `Windows` key, type 'path', choose 'Edit the system environment variables', click 'Environment Variables', find `Path` variable in `System variables` and in `User variables` then edit.

Comment: This explanation is a little cryptic but I managed to solve the issue by reading well what is said here and "interpret" Alex's intentions: apply step 1.2 *whilst* installing the application in step 1, and only after that go to step 2.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin` in my case, since I installed the Git client and it uses mingw64

Comment: On Windows, once you have edited the PATH in System Environment Variables, remember you need to exit/kill any open command terminals you intend using, as they will not receive a PATH update.

Answer (score 18):

On Windows install https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/, that is all.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using an alpine based image with your Dockerfile

Install `build-base` which will be met with your requirements.

```
apk add build-base
```

Comment: Can you explain the intuition behind it

Comment: It contains several other packages that your OS might need including, g++, make, libc, libc-dev, gcc, etc.

Comment: this answer is savior!

Answer (score 9):

```
$ go env
```

check **CGO_ENABLED** if its **1** change it to **0** by

```
$export CGO_ENABLED=0
```

Comment: You have a typo, it should be: export CGO_ENABLED=0 (with "A")

Comment: inside a container?

Comment: This ended up working for my specifc use case. Only difference was for windows needed to run `go env -w GCO_ENABLED=0` on the CLI

Answer (score 5):

For my case :
os: windows 10

command:

`choco install mingw`

install choco if not installed:
Link:  https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-chocolatey-on-windows/

worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

The proper explanations why go build does not work for hyperledger in Windows environment are given as other answers.
For your compilation purposes, just to make it work without installing anything extra, you can try the following

```
go build --tags nopkcs11
```

It worked for me. I hope same works for you too.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! If you use Visual Studio Code as windows editor you can add this to your settings with the following setting: "go.buildTags": "nopkcs11"

Answer (score 4):

You can try - this is not a solution but a temp workaround

```
cgo_enabled=0 go build
```

Once you install gcc - and make sure %PATH has a way to find it (gcc.exe) - this should go away.

Also running this one will ensure the cgo_enabled variable will stay this way as long as terminal is open. That way you don't have to prefix it each time you do a build.

```
export cgo_enabled=0 go build
```

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu, what worked for me was to simply run:

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

Answer (score 4):

just followed instructions from following and it solve my issue

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

it ask to install Mingw-w64 via [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/)

important command is `pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`
then add `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to `PATH`

thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Ubuntu do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential.
```

If the above commands do not work do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe"
```

The main component contains applications that are free software, can be freely redistributed and are fully supported by the Ubuntu team. & The universe component is a snapshot of the free, open-source, and Linux world.

Then install package by following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential.
```

For more info click here: https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-problem-installing-build-essential-on-14-04-1-lts-duplicate/

Comment: There is no need of dot at the end of the command

Answer (score 3):

On Amazon Linux 2:

1. Install go

   wget https://go.dev/dl/go1.18.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz

   rm -rf /usr/local/go && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.18.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz

   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
2. Install gcc

   sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

I recommend using the package group, even though it can be done without it, because groupinstall gives you the necessary packages to compile software on Amazon Linux and Redhat, CentOS for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

on Ubuntu its very easy but on windows need to do it:

1. download MinGW on http://www.mingw.org/
2. install on basic package Gcc-g++ (see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu2MI.png]))
3. add on environment Patch of windows variables.
4. restart and continue with "go get ..."

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your `Dockerfile`

```
RUN apk add alpine-sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

gcc should not be necessary, unless you are cross compiling for a non-windows platform, or use cgo.
If you still need gcc, however, you should install MinGW, which provides a gcc port for Windows (Cygwin and msys should also work, although I have never actually tested this).

Edit: I see from your error message now, that it is a dependency that requires gcc. If you didn't already know this, gcc is a c/c++ compiler, and in this case it is probably needed to compile c source files included by a dependency or sub-dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Instruction to fix the "*exec: “gcc”: executable file not found in %PATH%*" error with MSYS2:

- Download MSYS2.
- Put MSYS2 folder into your $PATH.
- Start the MSYS2 command line program.
- **Run this command: `pacman -S gcc`**.

Comment: which path? I installed msys to `c:\tools\msys64` and I think i'm supposed to use `c:\tools\msys64\usr\bin` to my PATH is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly install the MINGW after GUI will automatically take.

http://mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can install gcc by Scoop:

```
scoop install gcc
```

Comment: Scoop is my preferred method, as it does not require admin privileges, and uses current user directory, which seems like the cleanest solution

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to download MingGW64
2. put MingGW64 folder into your $PATH
3. run go build xxx.go (with cgo library)

Answer (score 0):

Hi jaswanth the main problem is that you haven't register your %GO_HOME%\pkg\tool\windows_amd64 to yuour Environment Path.
%GO_HOME% is the repository where you install your go at the first time.

Answer (score 0):

same as other, just install tdm-gcc, but you can use its terminal, "MinGW", you can access it from start menu folder tdm-gcc, after start, browse to your project, and run it again

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Windows user and I downloaded tdm-gcc (**MinGW-w64 based**) from the link below:

**https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/**

After installation, it made a folder named "TDM-GCC-64".

I added "**C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin**" to my **PATH**, And it fixed my problem.