# cgo: exec gcc: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH Error in Egress operator installation

Tags: go, kubernetes, gcc, cgo, coredns

I am trying [Egress Operator](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator#egress-operator) for restricting the egress calls based on domain. I am using `Ubuntu 18` Hyper-V VM and I have all [prerequisites](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator#pre-requisites):

1. Azure repository to push images
2. `Kubebuilder` for code generation
3. `Kustomize` for building the Kubernetes manifests
4. `CoreDns` (default with k3s) pod running
5. `Golang` : `go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64`

But while [Testing locally](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator#testing-locally-against-a-remote-cluster) `make run` is giving below error:

```
root@Ubuntu18-Virtual-Machine:~/egress-operator# make run
go: creating new go.mod: module tmp
go get: added sigs.k8s.io/controller-tools v0.2.4
/root/go/bin/controller-gen object:headerFile=./hack/boilerplate.go.txt paths="./..."
Error: go [list -e -json -compiled=true -test=false -export=false -deps=true -find=false -tags ignore_autogenerated -- ./...]: exit status 2: # runtime/cgo
cgo: exec gcc: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Also after editing coredns deployment and coredns Corefile in ConfigMap, as mentioned in [coredns plugin setup](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator#setting-up-coredns-plugin) I am seeing blow error while executing [`make deploy`](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator#set-up-the-controller-manager-and-its-customresourcedefinition-in-the-cluster) command:

```
root@Ubuntu18-Virtual-Machine:~/egress-operator# make deploy IMG=MY_REPO/egress-operator:v0.1
go: creating new go.mod: module tmp
go get: added sigs.k8s.io/controller-tools v0.2.4
/root/go/bin/controller-gen "crd:trivialVersions=true" rbac:roleName=manager-role webhook paths="./..." output:crd:artifacts:config=config/crd/bases
Error: go [list -e -json -compiled=true -test=false -export=false -deps=true -find=false -tags ignore_autogenerated -- ./...]: exit status 2: # runtime/cgo
cgo: exec gcc: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Can someone let me know how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your environment doesn't have the gcc compiler installed. Please try this as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

or

```
sudo apt-get  build-dep  gcc
```

Then check if the installation is successful:

```
gcc --version
```

See also this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55705493/15407542).